# How to direct to a custom error page?

Tags: sharepoint, error-handling

In SharePoint,

I want to be able to direct to a custom error page if a 404 is reached.

However, after following:

[How to point to a custom 404 error Web page in Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 or in Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941329/en-us)

I'm unable to hit my custom error page when trying for entries such as:

http://localhost/adsdasad or something erroneus.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you build a custom c# console app as described?  Without that your custom 404 page will not show on the site collection.

Answer (score 2):

Add a wildcard handler in IIS for such urls.

[image: IIS configuration]

Comment: How would you do this? I'm looking at the properties for the SharePoint - 80 website, and don't see where I can add wildcard handlers.

Not entirely sure I know what they are.

Answer (score 0):

Those URL's are not being handled by your SharePoint configuration because IIS does not think that the should be handled by SharePoint. As [Chris points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644149/how-to-direct-to-a-custom-error-page/644165#644165) you should add custom 404 handling at the IIS level too.